# Why isn't time dilation invalid for small values of the lenght of the clock?

Tags: time-dilation

I have to say that I'm not really sophisticated in physics, as I'm studying pure math. Still, there is a question I carry with me since late High school, and I wanted to ask it now: I remember vagily that time dilation was proved/argued by a small computation that uses a vertical clock with two mirrors at the end and a light pulse bouncing between the two. Now, the lenght of the clock is assumed to be a positive number $L$, but I think I remember something of a "minimal measerable size in the universe". But what if we push the lenght $L$ under this size, why doesn't this calculation become invalid then? With other words, why does this reasoning for time dilation doesn't become invalid for these small values of $L$?

I would be very grateful if someone could explain this to me in terms that I can understand.

Comment: What did you mean by the 'minimal measurable size'?

Comment: @MarcoOcram I assume they mean the Planck length.

Comment: @MarcoOcram I guess it's about $10^{-35}$ meter? I think I remember it as Planck-space. I would be glad if you can correct me a bit if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

In special relativity, there is no smallest length or shortest time beyond which the theory stops working. It is a theory that applies to all length and time scales. There may be theories other than special relativity that predict that time dilation breaks down at some length/time scale, but such theories have no bearing on the predictions of special relativity.

Answer (score 2):

You proved something by thinking about a clock.  You are worried that you couldn't have proved it by thinking about some other clock.  Okay, you also couldn't have proved it by thinking about the 1959 World Series.  All you need is one proof, and you have that proof.  The fact that some other attempted proof might not work won't change that fact.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured out my mistake. I guess I thought before that time dilation uses the size of the object, and then if the object is too small, the argument behind it becomes invalid. If I remember correctly, the argument in time dilation uses an arbitrary positive size of the clock, and of course the mathematical argument doesn't change, but why doesn't it need to be adjusted to the hypothesis that the lenght is "big enough"?

Comment: 1)  All valid clocks have to run at the same speed in any given frame   (if they ran at the same speed in my frame and different speeds in yours, we could deduce that you are moving, which relativity does not allow).  2)  So if **any one** of your clocks runs slow in my frame, then they all do.  3)  We figured out that one particular clock of yours runs slow in my frame.  The argument we used might not apply to some other clock.  But that doesn't matter.  We know of one clock that runs slow, so we know they all do.

Comment: Thanks, your first point is of axiomatic nature, is that correct?

Comment: In fact, why worry about short light clocks any more than you worry about hourglasses, wristwatches and clocks in bell towers?  The argument doesn't apply to them either.  But again, no matter.  We already proved that one clock runs slow, from which it follows that all do.

Comment: Yes, the first point is an axiom of relativity.

Comment: But if I ask you about a proof for time dilatation to convince me(and we assume I don't know any yet), and the first you would say is the argument with the light clocks, why don't you need to add the assumption that the clock is long enough, so that the argument is valid? Because if not, at that point I woulnd't have a valid proof, using this method. Of course, you can say there are other methods, but if I don't know them yet, I woulnd't accept the one with the light clock at this point.

Comment: @Thanks:  First of all, in relativity there is no minimum length so your concern doesn't matter anyway.  But second of all, if it makes you more comfortable to add that assumption, feel free.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I came to see my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is whether the simple argument to show the necessity for time dilation by observing a moving light clock might break down if the length of the clock is less than the Planck length.

The question is very much one of principle, since it is impossible to exaggerate how utterly impractical it would be to create and operate such a clock.

There are many theoretical models to do with quantum gravity particularly that suggest that the principles of relativity break down at scales approaching the Planck length- an effect known as Lorenz Invariance Violation (LIV). If the implications of those models were true, then the speed of light would not necessarily be the same for all observers at those scales, so the standard arguments we use to figure out the effects of relativity would indeed break down.

If you are interested, there is an introductory article on Wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_searches_for_Lorentz_violation .

Comment: Actually I think in this context my question arose. I heard that relativity and quantum theory are somewhat hard to combine, and in my simple-thinking High school mind I thought "Of course, the argument becomes invalid if the lenght is small". Thanks for clearing this up a bit!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a variation of " why isnt time dilation invalid at quantum scales "

I think the answer is that, it IS invalid. Relativity is not applicable in the quantum scale. Relativity and quantum mechanics are famously not compatible. A unified theory that is applicable at both scales would be some sort of holy grail in physics.

Comment: Thank you. I somehwat have the impression that this is a bit contradictory to the answer of @d_b above. I would be glad if you could explain a bit why it isn't.

Comment: @Thanks. It is contradictory because the other answer is inaccurate in some parts. particularly where he says " It is a theory that applies to all length and time scales. ". Relativity does not apply at quantum scales